# What do the CBCharacteristicProperties mean?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

In the iOS CBCharacteristic Class Reference, there is a description of the bit map used to return the properties of a characteristic. I am looking for information on what three of them mean.

The documentation lists them as follows:

**CBCharacteristicProperties**

The possible properties of a characteristic.

```
enum {
    CBCharacteristicPropertyBroadcast = 0x01,
    CBCharacteristicPropertyRead = 0x02,
    CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse = 0x04,
    CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite = 0x08,
    CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify = 0x10,
    CBCharacteristicPropertyIndicate = 0x20,
    CBCharacteristicPropertyAuthenticatedSignedWrites = 0x40,
    CBCharacteristicPropertyExtendedProperties = 0x80,
};
```

There is no other documentation or listing of these properties that I could find.

Some are obvious, like Read, Write and Notify. Broadcast is documented in other BLE documentation I found.

CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse is confusing. Why is this a flag? The CBDevice call writeValue:forCharacteristic:type: has a flag that accepts the following:

```
enum {
    CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse = 0,
    CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse,
};
```

Are these flags redundant, or do you have to supply a type to writeValue:forCharacteristic:type: that matches the CBCharacteristicProperties flag?

Also, what do CBCharacteristicPropertyIndicate and CBCharacteristicPropertyExtendedProperties mean?

Is there a better reference than Apple's documentation that explains these?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got this answer on the Apple Developer Forums:

> It helps to understand the underlying specificaiton. If you have a
>   look at the GATT section in the Host volume of the 4.0 spec (available
>   here: http://www.bluetooth.org/Technical/Specifications/adopted.htm)
>   the constants should be clearer.
>   CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse indicates that the
>   characteristic suports the 'Write without Response' sub-procedure.
>   CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse indicates you actually want to
>   use the 'Write without Response' sub-procedure. Presumably trying to
>   use the 'Write without Response' sub-procedure on a characteristic
>   that does not support it will result in an error.   Hope that helps,
>
> Ben

As a follow up, the document in question is [Core Version 4.0](http://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=229737). See section *3.3.1.1 Characteristic Properties*.

Comment: Page 1898 of the linked document (there is more than one section 3) the one you need is within the Generic Attribute Profile (GATT) sub-document starting on page 1879.